# Rails 4, disposition: 'attachment' is not downloading in iOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, download, content-disposition

I am passing **disposition: 'attachment'** in send_data method to download image and it works flawlessly on all the platforms **but iOS**. In iOs it is behaving as if **disposition: 'inline'** was passed. I am stuck and unable to figure it out. It would be really appreciable if any one could help.

I am using **Rails 4.2.6** with **Ruby 2.3.4**

My code in view is

```
<%= link_to "Download", blog_blogs_download_image_path, data: {turbolinks: false} %>
```

and in controller

```
require 'open-uri'
url = 'resource_path'
data = open(url).read
send_data data, filename: "test_photo.jpg", disposition: 'attachment'
```

Answer (score -1):

AFAIU, that's the way it is. There's no concept of "downloads" in iOS.